# Issue with slider and overflow

Tags: jquery, html, css, slider, overflow

I'm trying to get Unslider to work - right now it's a list of images on top of each other..

HTML:

```
<div id="main">
<div class="slider">
    <ul>
        <li><img src="images/slider1.jpg" /></li>
        <li><img src="images/slider2.jpg" /></li>
        <li><img src="images/slider3.jpg" /></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
main {max-width:900px;
           margin-left:auto;
           margin-right:auto;}

.slider { position: relative; overflow: auto; width:900px;}
        .slider li { list-style: none; }
            .slider ul li { float: left; }

ul {padding: 0;
    margin: 0;}
```

Comment: Can you create a `fiddle` demonstrating your issue? (just plug your code in there and then hit update and share the url) http://jsfiddle.net/Zq8vm/ might be a good start because it already has the Unslider js file loaded.

Comment: I don't think I'm using this right...http://jsfiddle.net/Zq8vm/12/

Comment: See: http://jsfiddle.net/trevordowdle/Zq8vm/13/ The fiddle you gave seems to work properly.. That would mean that maybe the unslider javascript file is not being properly loaded in your webpage.

Comment: Do you have a `script` tag pointing to your `unslider javascript file?` something like: <script src="/Javascripts/unslider.min.js"></script> or <script src="http://unslider.com/unslider.min.js"></script> this could be added right before your ending `</body>` tag.

Comment: I linked to the source code on Unslider's website. It shows as a stack when I view in the browser from Dreamweaver, but on the actual website (http://www.lotusroomofboca.com/learn_more.html) it's nonexistent until the second slide comes up.

Comment: these are all the links I have in the code:
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="//unslider.com/unslider.min.js"></script>

Comment: I'm guessing the image needs to load completely before the slider can be initialized... Check my answer, hopefully that will fix it for you.

Comment: Got it. Unslider didn't provide the script code with "http". I had to add it.

Comment: The answer I posted below may help, so that the slider shows the first slide before the second slide comes up.  Have you tried it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( ".slider img:first" ).load(function() {
        $('.slider').unslider({
            speed: 700,              
            delay: 5000,         
            complete: function() {}, 
            keys: true,              
            dots: false, 
            fluid: false,      
        });
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/trevordowdle/Zq8vm/14/

Comment: Thank you, but I found that adding the missing "http" to the script links fixed this issue.

Comment: @Marissa your welcome but i'm still seeing that when you go to lotusroomofboca.com/learn_more.html `it's nonexistent until the second slide comes up.`  Did adding the `http` fix that?  My answer above is trying to help with that.

Comment: Yes, I've updated everything in Dreamweaver, haven't updated the hosted site yet.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this can be an an issue with the default browser styling of the ul.
See my example [here](http://codepen.io/davidsturgeon/pen/KzpiA), uncomment the ul styling to see the fix.

This can also be fixed by using a [CSS Reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)

Comment: Adding your code worked to fix the div issue. Thank you. However, I still don't know how to get the slider to be a slider instead of stacked images. The reset didn't fix it.